# Edittext have to be focus always

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

I have an EditText. I want this edittext to always be in focus and writeable. How can I do this without touching it every time? Because barcode scanner machine sends data successive to this app.

```
anasayfa_barkod.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                geciciListeyeEkle();
                listeyiYukle();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                tutarYazdir();

                if(anasayfa_verilenUcret.getText().length()>0){
                    try{
                        String ucret=anasayfa_verilenUcret.toString();
                        String paraustu=String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(ucret)-gelenSatis);
                        anasayfa_paraustu.setText(paraustu);
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                anasayfa_barkod.requestFocus(); //not working
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I tried a lot of method.but all of them is not working. I can set the keyboard is visible but cursor not on edittext.

Comment: `editText.requestFocus()` Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295802/how-to-make-edittext-not-focused-when-creating-activity and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext

Comment: this is not working

Comment: show us your code this is not the way you should ask questions on SO better read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972214/edittext-focus-disappears-when-the-barcode-scanner-reads-the-barcode)

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if ( anasayfa_barkod!= null) {
                            anasayfa_barkod.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think may I can help. Use this in onCreate method

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

it works for me.

Comment: or you can use this  **EditText.setSelected(true);**

Comment: try **EditText.setFocusable(true);**

Comment: put this in your xml in editText tag **android:setFocusable="true"**

Answer (score 0):

If you are in activity add this in your onCreate method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT‌​_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_‌​VISIBLE);
```

if you are in fragment use this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT‌​_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_‌​VISIBLE);
```

Comment: try this:

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT‌​_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_‌​VISIBLE);`

`EditText.requestFocus()`
`EditText.performClicked()`